# How do I set a chromium command line flag in Electron?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron, chromium

I am working on an Electron app and need to enable the following Chromium flag `GuestViewCrossProcessFrames` to make scaling work with webview.

I tried calling the following line in my main.js but it doesn't seem to work. Also tried enabling plugins for the BrowserWindow as well as webview.

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('--enable-features=GuestViewCrossProcessFrames');
```

Can someone help me setting up this flag? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

you can set by calling

```
const { app } = require('electron');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-features', 'GuestViewCrossProcessFrames');
app.on('ready', () => {
// place your code.
}
```

note: you need to call it before ready event emitted.

Comment: for me, this method works when I run my app from the command line (script:  `electron .`).  But it does nothing when I run the packaged app.  Any idea why the difference?

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me why Electron does this though specific flag you specified is explicitly disabled in electron

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/bcbcb4c6436e84e7f1f2387c2d7581bbdadb5732/brightray/browser/browser_main_parts.cc#L185-L187

So you can't enable it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appcommandlineappendswitchswitch-value), the proper way of calling `appendSwitch` is:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch(switch[, value])
```

As mentioned in [OJ Kwon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51449330/2752041), apparently `enable-features` is explicitly disabled by Electron. If that wasn't true, you would be able to set it with the following syntax:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-features', 'GuestViewCrossProcessFrames');
```

See [Supported Chrome Command Line Switches](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/command-line-switches) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use app.commandLine.appendSwitch be sure to not use '--' your call should look like this

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-features=GuestViewCrossProcessFrames');
```

Comment: I haven't tested your method - perhaps it works, but I believe the more standard way to do this is to split the flag and value separately: app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-features', 'GuestViewCrossProcessFrames');